# Allow horizontal scroll on one div, but not on entire body

Tags: html, css, scroll

[Demo](http://cdpn.io/7065ff09d421d6863c287259a07fe0ef)

I've got a page with three sections that are 100% width and 100% height of the body with the exception of one section which is 200% the width of the body. On this section I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally to see the rest of the div, but I don't want the rest of the sections to have white space to the right of them as they currently do. If I set `body{ overflow-x:hidden;}` I can't scroll horizontally on the wider div. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to encase the `width:200%;` div inside a container that has 100% width, so that it stays within the body, then set the container to `overflow-x:auto;`

[Here is a jsFiddle to show what i mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/UGkvD/)